# DataFrame groupby and shifting values based on freq

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am trying to groupby my DataFrame and shift some columns for 1 day.
Code for the test df:

```
    import pandas as pd
    import datetime as dt

    d = {'date' : ['202211', '202211', '202211','202211','202211', '202212', '202212', '202212', '202212', '202213', '202213', '202213', '202213', '202213'],
         'id' : ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd','e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
         'price' : [1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.5, 1.7, 2, 1.5, 2, 1.1, 2, 1.5, 0.8, 1.3, 1.5],
         'shrs' : [100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
    df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y%m%d')
    df.set_index('date', inplace=True)
    df["me"] = df['price'] * df['shrs']
    df['rank'] = df.groupby('date')['price'].transform(lambda x: pd.qcut(x, 2, labels=range(1,3), 
    duplicates='drop'))
    df['weight'] = df['me'] / (df.groupby(['date', 'rank'])['me'].transform('sum'))
    df['ew'] = 1 / (df.groupby(['date', 'rank'])['price'].transform('count'))
    df.sort_values(['id', 'date'], inplace=True)
    print(df)
```

```
               id  price  shrs     me rank    weight        ew
    date                                                      
    2022-01-01  a    1.0   100  100.0    1  0.285714  0.333333
    2022-01-02  a    2.0   100  200.0    2  0.500000  0.500000
    2022-01-03  a    2.0   100  200.0    2  1.000000  1.000000
    2022-01-01  b    1.2   100  120.0    1  0.342857  0.333333
    2022-01-02  b    1.5   100  150.0    1  0.576923  0.500000
    2022-01-03  b    1.5   100  150.0    1  0.294118  0.250000
    2022-01-01  c    1.3   100  130.0    1  0.371429  0.333333
    2022-01-02  c    2.0   100  200.0    2  0.500000  0.500000
    2022-01-03  c    0.8   100   80.0    1  0.156863  0.250000
    2022-01-01  d    1.5   100  150.0    2  0.468750  0.500000
    2022-01-02  d    1.1   100  110.0    1  0.423077  0.500000
    2022-01-03  d    1.3   100  130.0    1  0.254902  0.250000
    2022-01-01  e    1.7   100  170.0    2  0.531250  0.500000
    2022-01-03  e    1.5   100  150.0    1  0.294118  0.250000
```

The following code results almost in what I want. But as my data is not consistent and some days might be skipped (see observations for id "e"), I need cannot do simply shift(1) but need to implement the frequency as well.

```
df['rank'] = df.groupby('id')['rank'].shift(1)
df['weight'] = df.groupby('id')['weight'].shift(1)
df['ew'] = df.groupby('id')['ew'].shift(1)
print(df)
```

results in:

```
           id  price  shrs     me rank    weight        ew
date                                                      
2022-01-01  a    1.0   100  100.0  NaN       NaN       NaN
2022-01-02  a    2.0   100  200.0    1  0.285714  0.333333
2022-01-03  a    2.0   100  200.0    2  0.500000  0.500000
2022-01-01  b    1.2   100  120.0  NaN       NaN       NaN
2022-01-02  b    1.5   100  150.0    1  0.342857  0.333333
2022-01-03  b    1.5   100  150.0    1  0.576923  0.500000
2022-01-01  c    1.3   100  130.0  NaN       NaN       NaN
2022-01-02  c    2.0   100  200.0    1  0.371429  0.333333
2022-01-03  c    0.8   100   80.0    2  0.500000  0.500000
2022-01-01  d    1.5   100  150.0  NaN       NaN       NaN
2022-01-02  d    1.1   100  110.0    2  0.468750  0.500000
2022-01-03  d    1.3   100  130.0    1  0.423077  0.500000
2022-01-01  e    1.7   100  170.0  NaN       NaN       NaN
2022-01-03  e    1.5   100  150.0    2  0.531250  0.500000
```

The desired outcome would be (watch observation for id "e"):

```
           id  price  shrs     me rank    weight        ew
date                                                      
2022-01-01  a    1.0   100  100.0  NaN       NaN       NaN
2022-01-02  a    2.0   100  200.0    1  0.285714  0.333333
2022-01-03  a    2.0   100  200.0    2  0.500000  0.500000
2022-01-01  b    1.2   100  120.0  NaN       NaN       NaN
2022-01-02  b    1.5   100  150.0    1  0.342857  0.333333
2022-01-03  b    1.5   100  150.0    1  0.576923  0.500000
2022-01-01  c    1.3   100  130.0  NaN       NaN       NaN
2022-01-02  c    2.0   100  200.0    1  0.371429  0.333333
2022-01-03  c    0.8   100   80.0    2  0.500000  0.500000
2022-01-01  d    1.5   100  150.0  NaN       NaN       NaN
2022-01-02  d    1.1   100  110.0    2  0.468750  0.500000
2022-01-03  d    1.3   100  130.0    1  0.423077  0.500000
2022-01-01  e    1.7   100  170.0  NaN       NaN       NaN
2022-01-03  e    1.5   100  150.0  NaN       NaN       NaN
```

I did not manage to simply use `freq='d'` here. What could be the easiest solution?

Answer (score 0):

One quick and dirty solution that works with your data is to `unstack()` and `stack()` the `id` column to create nulls for the gaps and then drop the nulls at the end:

```
In [50]: df = df.set_index('id', append=True).unstack().stack(dropna=False).reset_index(level=1).sort_values('id')

In [51]: df['rank'] = df.groupby('id')['rank'].shift(1)
    ...: df['weight'] = df.groupby('id')['weight'].shift(1)
    ...: df['ew'] = df.groupby('id')['ew'].shift(1)

In [52]: print(df[df['price'].notnull()])
           id  price   shrs     me rank    weight        ew
date
2022-01-01  a    1.0  100.0  100.0  NaN       NaN       NaN
2022-01-02  a    2.0  100.0  200.0    1  0.285714  0.333333
2022-01-03  a    2.0  100.0  200.0    2  0.500000  0.500000
2022-01-01  b    1.2  100.0  120.0  NaN       NaN       NaN
2022-01-02  b    1.5  100.0  150.0    1  0.342857  0.333333
2022-01-03  b    1.5  100.0  150.0    1  0.576923  0.500000
2022-01-01  c    1.3  100.0  130.0  NaN       NaN       NaN
2022-01-02  c    2.0  100.0  200.0    1  0.371429  0.333333
2022-01-03  c    0.8  100.0   80.0    2  0.500000  0.500000
2022-01-01  d    1.5  100.0  150.0  NaN       NaN       NaN
2022-01-02  d    1.1  100.0  110.0    2  0.468750  0.500000
2022-01-03  d    1.3  100.0  130.0    1  0.423077  0.500000
2022-01-01  e    1.7  100.0  170.0  NaN       NaN       NaN
2022-01-03  e    1.5  100.0  150.0  NaN       NaN       NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `resample` on a groupby to generate a daily series:

```py
# Resample to produce a daily data for each ID
shifted = df.groupby("id").resample("1D").first().groupby(level=0).shift()

# `shifted` and `df`'s indexes must have the same shape
df = df.set_index("id", append=True).swaplevel()

# Rely on panda's auto row alignment to handle the assignment
cols = ["rank", "weight", "ew"]
df[cols] = shifted[cols]
df.reset_index(0, inplace=True)
```